# How to update multiple many to many relationship and check for concurrency exceptions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I was wondering how could I update an entity with multiple many to many relationships. So if I had a car model with many connectors, inputvoltages, lenstypes and lightcolors. I want the user to be able to update all selections on one page and so when they submit the page all connectors, lights, etc are added or removed from the car. I was wondering if I should use a ViewModel and have each entity on the ViewModel or use the view-bag and pass a list of items. For when the user saves if someone else added or removed something from the car then the page will re-display itself. I'm using MVC5 with c# and Entity Framework 6

Example model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bob.Models
{
public partial class Car
 {
    public Car()
    {

        this.Connectors = new List<Connector>();
        this.InputVoltages = new List<InputVoltage>();
        this.LensTypes = new List<LensType>();
        this.LightColors = new List<LightColor>();

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

}

    public ICollection<Connector> Connectors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InputVoltage> InputVoltages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LightType> LensTypes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LightColor> LightColors { get; set; }

 }
}
```

Example Controller actions

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.PossibleLightColors = lightcolorRepository.All;
         return View(carRepository.Find(id));
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Car car)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            carRepository.InsertOrUpdate(car);
            carRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } else {
            ViewBag.PossibleLightColors = lightcolorRepository.All;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In regards to "if I should use a ViewModel and have each entity on the ViewModel" - I would prefer a ViewModel approach in this case. 

Similar to you domain Car model expose a Car View model property and have seperate view models for Connectors, InputVoltages, LensTypes  etc

Strongly typed models are always recommended for a page level data oppose to ViewBag which is typically use for small set of data such as page title, an header etc. Also strongly typed Views make the code cleaner and more easy to maintain.

Comment: check my Question, Marcos post may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009536/insert-view-with-collection-property